# scrollTop offset for nav hide on scroll down

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, show-hide

I'm using a script for hiding the nav when scrolling down and showing it again when scrolling up. But on iOS the menu disappears because there is a 'bounce' when you hit the top of the page. I was thinking that an offset for triggering the script on the top of the page could fix this, or is there an other way?

```
var prev = 0;
var $window = $(window);
var nav = $('#top-bar-container');

$window.on('scroll', function(){
  var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
  nav.toggleClass('hidden', scrollTop > prev);
  prev = scrollTop;
});
```

```
.hidden {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  transition-duration: 0.6s !important;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it with the code below that automatically added the menubar height as an offset.

```
var previousScroll = 0,
    headerOrgOffset = $('#top-bar-container').height();

// $('#top-bar-container').height(); <--- this is not needed I guess. 

$(window).scroll(function () {
    var currentScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (currentScroll > headerOrgOffset) {
        if (currentScroll > previousScroll) {
            $('#top-bar-container').addClass('hidden');
        } else {
            $('#top-bar-container').removeClass('hidden');
        }
    } else {
            $('#top-bar-container').removeClass('hidden');
    }
    previousScroll = currentScroll;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about checking if scrollTop is also 0?
Maybe like this:

```
var prev = 0;
var $window = $(window);
var nav = $('#nav');

$(window).scroll(function(){
    var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
    
    if(scrollTop < prev || scrollTop == 0){
        console.log("up");
        nav.show();
    }
    else{
        console.log("down");
        nav.hide();
    }
        
    prev = scrollTop
});
```